# How to alert the user that they might delete sensitive data?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, syntax

This is the pop-up message that shows up if the user decides to delete sensitive data. Could it be better phrased?

> WARNING!
>
> You are about to delete sensitive data in background.  In this mode, any filtering or
>   individual selection from the list will be IGNORED.  Only the
>   parameters from the previous selection screen are passed for deletion.

Context: the user is deleting data selected from the previous selection screen; however, an ALV grid is displayed where users can make selections. This selection will be ignored and everything from the ALV gets deleted.

Comment: What is an ALV grid?

Comment: Even as a computer professional, I have difficulty understanding the context of what you want to say.  Why would you warn people you're only deleting part of their input?  It seems a poor design choice.

Comment: I understand it is a very poor design choice but unfortunately the implementation is already done. As for the deletion, it deletes everything from the list (filters are ignored). @Peter, an ALV grid looks like [this](http://www.itpsap.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/ALV-Grid1.jpg)

Comment: Oh dear, you've gone to the Dark Side (SAP)... there is no coming back!.... For the screen that the user is looking at (which has the query filtering), will everything on that screen be deleted? Why is the ALV grid being shown??

Comment: @Peter haha yes indeed! yes everything on that screen will be deleted but the issue is that all filters will be ignored and all the data first shown in the grid will be deleted.

Comment: This question should be somewhere else in my opinion. The English isn't the issue here, it's the system design. It's a bad idea to give the user the opportunity to filter if that doesn't have any effect. Maybe try http://ux.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @AlexK It's a standard English usage case: "If you can't fix it, blag your way out of it..."

Comment: @Peter I agree! The way out here is with some nice use of English. But the problem isn't the grammar or the phrasing from the English language perspective, but the wording from a UX perspective and what it'll mean to the user.

Comment: You may force the user to remove any filter, if one is activated. Something like *please first remove any filter*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agree with comments that the best solution would be to make the system/UX design better to remove this possible confusion, but if this is really not possible then (provided I am properly understanding the situation you describe) I would go with something like:

> WARNING!
>
> You are about to delete data.
>
> **All** data will be deleted, regardless of any filters which have been applied.
>
> To view the data which will be deleted, first remove all filters.

Or something to that effect, making it clear to the user that their delete command could delete more data than just what they can currently see on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Since the implementation seems to already be set in stone, the best thing to do would be to **deactivate any filters** and have a message that whatever the user is looking at will be deleted:

> **YOU ARE ABOUT TO DELETE THE WORLD AS YOU KNOW IT!!!**
>   Are you sure??
>   Are you really sure??
>   Are you really, really sure??

Showing what will be deleted is good, but to ensure that the filters/controls need to be deactivated (which should be trivial, even for SAP).

> WARNING!
>
> **PLEASE BE CAREFUL** with any data you are about to delete.
>   **PLEASE CHECK** the complete list of entries to be deleted.
>   **PLEASE REMOVE** any filters or selections to ensure correct deletion.
>
> Or you may ruin the rest of your day, as well as the sysadmin's.

One thing's for sure, if the user does it incorrectly, it probably won't happen more than once...